# How to make an object to follow a path in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, animation, opengl, glut, bezier

I have an object that I made in Blender and I need it to follow a path, the path is a Bezier curve that I generated and then I saved all the curve points in a list. So I have `List<Point> Points`the things is that I don't know how to make the object to follow that list of points, I was doing it in the `glutIdleFunc` but then I realized that it was wrong because it will iterate through the list everytime the program is Idle... so I thought like iterate through the list every 100 milliseconds using the `glutTimerFunc` but how? I tried that but it draws the object all weird.

Here is some code:

```
void timer(int value)
{
   std::string str2 = "Body";
   std::list<Point>::iterator itBezier0 = BezierPoints.begin(), itBezier1 = BezierPoints.begin();
    ++itBezier1;

   for(std::list<Object>::iterator it = OBJ.begin(); it!=OBJ.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(it->name.compare(str2) == 1)
        { //BODY
            for(list<Face>::iterator it2 = it->faces.begin(); it2 != it->faces.end(); ++it2)
            {   //FACES LIST
                for(list<Vertex>::iterator it3 = it2->vertices.begin(); it3 != it2->vertices.end(); ++it3)
                {
                    it3->X = it3->X + (itBezier1->X - itBezier0->X);
                    it3->Y = it3->Y + (itBezier1->Y - itBezier0->Y);
                    it3->Z = it3->Z + (itBezier1->Z - itBezier0->Z);
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(list<Face>::iterator it2 = it->faces.begin(); it2 != it->faces.end(); ++it2)
            {   //FACES LIST
                for(list<Vertex>::iterator it3 = it2->vertices.begin(); it3 != it2->vertices.end(); ++it3)
                {
                    it3->X = it3->X + (itBezier1->X - itBezier0->X);
                    it3->Y = it3->Y + (itBezier1->Y - itBezier0->Y);
                    it3->Z = it3->Z + (itBezier1->Z - itBezier0->Z);

                }

            }
        }

    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(100, timer, 1);
}
```

This is the main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize (1280, 720);
    glutInitWindowPosition (0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow ("BB-8");
    init ();
    OBJ = ReadObject();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(spinBody);
    glutTimerFunc(100, timer, 1);
    glutSpecialFunc(keySpecial); // Tell GLUT to use the method "keyPressed" for key presses
    glutSpecialUpFunc(keySpecialUp); // Tell GLUT to use the method "keyUp" for key up events
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Can your question be simplified to "How to call a function every 100ms (glut available)?" If not please explain why not.

Comment: I think not, because what I need is to iterate through the list every 100ms? I'm confused

Comment: Have a static or global counter. Inside a function increase it. Use it as an index into your list of points. Reposition the object once in the function, to the indexed point. Call the function once every 100ms. That, I imagine would reduce your question to how to call every 100ms. Is anything about that unclear? You can then draw the object as often as you like, to make the needed FPS.